# Retrieve documents by subdocument Id in MongoDb and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In one of my collections I have subdocuments for each document, I need to retrieve those documents by subdocument id.

My Article Schema look like this,

```
   var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        userName:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        comment:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    })

    var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        title:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        description:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        comments:[commentSchema]
    })
```

I have tried this method but it always returns a null array

```
router.get('/posts/comments/:commentId', function(req, res){
    let commentId = req.params.commentId;
    Article.find({comments: {_id: commentId}}, function(err, posts){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(posts);

    })
});
```

Is there any other way to retrieve all the documents which contains a paticular subdocument id?